# javascript is not loading in django template....or its not working in django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

this is my html page where am loading js file

```
<!DOCTYPE html> {% load static %}
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/grid.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/post.css' %}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/post.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

</head>
```

and this is my js file in static/js/post.js

```
$(".sidebar-dropdown > a").click(function() {
$(".sidebar-submenu").slideUp(200);
if (
    $(this)
    .parent()
    .hasClass("active")
) {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
    $(this)
        .parent()
        .removeClass("active");
} else {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
    $(this)
        .next(".sidebar-submenu")
        .slideDown(200);
    $(this)
        .parent()
        .addClass("active");
}
});

$("#close-sidebar").click(function() {
    $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
});
$("#show-sidebar").click(function() {
    $(".page-wrapper").addClass("toggled");
    });
```

what should i do...am not facing any error but its not working ...is there any kind of inheriting problem ?

Comment: Grab your static files URLs from rendered page and try to open it manually in the browser. Can you access them?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to move the import of your post.js file outside the head and at the end of your  HTML tag. The way you import it it could be parsed and executed before jquery is actually here, causing an error.

If you could give us the console logs client side it could help aswell!